# if an element has a particular class do sth on another element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question with `.hasClass` method in jquery.

For example I want my menu button color to become red when my `div` element with `.show` class exists.

So I have written this code for explain this solution

```
 if ($(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("show"))
    $(".menuIcon").css("color", "red");
```

but this code didn't work when I tested...
how can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you post your target code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is totally correct , and it should works . just make sure of
 1- your jquery library is exists and loaded coreectly .
 2- the styles associated with your code is exists in the page and true
 3- contain your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ });` to ensure the styles are loaded before the code excuted .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if ($(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("show")){
         $(".menuIcon").css("color", "red");
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".navbar-collapse.show").find(".menuIcon").css("color", "red");
```

You can associate it with the event that changes the menu.

Comment: no it is not about {} it will work when I test another example

Answer (score 0):

Only with css:

```
.navbar-collapse.show {
    color:red!important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be ok, but the behavior you are experiencing can be due to one or more of the following:

- you might be missing to include jquery (include it using the `script` tag if so)
- you might have an error in your console (fix it if so)
- your code might be executed before your tag having the `show` `class` is created or before the `show` `class` is being added to the tag
- the `show` `class` might be added to another tag
- you might want to override `background-color` instead of `color`
- another javascript might override your desired behavior

To get a more exact response, you need to ask a more exact question.

Comment: I think it could be about !important keyword in css

Comment: @mr.md !important overrides any other rule. What rule is !important in your case?